# Joining data of two different datasets from varying distances and integrating into one dataset in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, sql, select

I have a pointfile of some 200 electrical boxes throughout the county. While the electrical boxes are "mapped", they are done so by using township range section data, so there actual location is not known. They are simply at the centroid of a section or subsection. My task is to verify their real world location and move them from the cetroid of the section or subsection to that real location.

I have a 2nd pointfile of electrical boxes that have been GPS located by workers from a utility company. This pointfile contains some 70 features that I know their location is correct. However, only 40 of the points in this file correspond to the 200 in the above file.

Both files contain a unique identifying number for all of the electrical boxes allowing for a 1:1 join of the files to be completed as the GPS points need the attribute data that is present on the county dat. However, since a tabular join like that doesn't actually change any spatial data, it isn't enough to call the job finished. I need to get the attribute data from the 200 to the matching 40, while eliminating those 40 points from the 200. I then need merge the 40 GPS'd points into the county dataset, so all my points are unified in one single file.

I cannot do a spatial join on these two files, because the distances between the GPS verified and the 200 from the county are not uniform due to the TSR mapping of the county data. In other words, joining them based off distance X wouldn't work because the closest points will not necessarily match in real life.

What I really need is to be able to select attributes across two different datasets. I tried merging the two and then running a selection of where UNIQUE_NO = UNIQUE_NO1, but while it was verified it returned no results.

Any idea how to move forward on this? Working in ArcMap 10.2

Comment: After you join by attributes you can either calculate fields or export the feature class which will append the joined fields... is that what you're after?

Comment: I don't believe that solves the problem as it is still only fiddling with the attribute data while it is the locations of the points and the need to merge the two files while deleting the redundant data is the issue.

Comment: When you join the GPS points to the attributes of the Electrical Boxes the geometry is that of the GPS points with the attributes of the Electrical Boxes - the correct location with the correct attributes, you just need to do a bit of juggling to get the fields right. Exporting the joined feature class makes the fields permanent (no longer joined). I don't know about your data structure so can't advise the best course.

Comment: Ah yes, that does work and I have tried it, however there are some significant problems that arise that have kept me from taking this course of action to completion. Mainly about the "juggling to get the fields right" aspect. 

While going county data -> GPS data yields 40 matches, going GPS -> County only finds 32 matches. So when I am to reintegrate that the GPS data with the joined attribute data from the county back into the county file for a single unified file, it there are 8 redundant points in the file that need to be purged. Since my SQL selections on the joined file return empty

Comment: results, that means I'd have to do it by hand. Normally that wouldn't be a problem since I could just muscle through 200 records, but I'll be doin this same scenario for all the counties in my state. Hardly an ideal solution. Also merging the joined file back into a single file results in a total flood of attribute fields that are all differently populated.

Comment: You can find the duplicate entries using summary statistics (count of unique id) then select any 'unique' id that has a count > 1. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000 in the end though 'data cleansing' is always painful and involves some 'muscle work'.. hopefully that would make it a little easier to find where to apply the 'muscle'.

Comment: Have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141177/how-to-add-a-point-to-existing-attribute-record-rather-than-edit-attributes-of/141198#141198 It seems to me that you are trying to modify geometry, while keeping the rest of attributes the same. If this is a case I can post a script, that I am using.

Comment: If you're joining on an identical field and getting two different match result counts depending on direction, something isn't right there and I'd investigate that. Perhaps you already have duplicate records in one file or the other. There are two approaches you can take - joining the data/transferring attributes, or replacing the geometry as Felix and the current answer suggests. Personally, I'd go for the geometry replacement since you're approaching this from and 'update' standpoint rather than a 'replace all'.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the location of the points on the `bad` shapefile to that of the `good` doing a join and then using the Field Calculator to update the location:

1. Using ArcToolbox>Add XY to the good shapefile, if not already in attributes.
2. Perform the Join.
3. Now that the `bad` shapefile has the attributes you need AND the `POINT_X` AND `POINT_Y` fields, you can update the `SHAPE` attributes using the Field Calculator.
4. Using the Calculate Field Tool. (You could also use the Field Calculator)

   ```
   Parser:
   Python

   Field Name:
   SHAPE

   Expression:
   updateCoords(!POINT_X!, !POINT_Y!)

   Code Block:
   def updateCoords(new_x, new_y):           
      point = arcpy.Point()
      point.X = new_x
      point.Y = new_y
   return point
   ```
5. The `bad` shapefile should now coincide with the `good`.
6. Continue with workflow to merge into master.